# Pandas Interpolate Returning NaNs

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, time-series, interpolation

I'm trying to do basic interpolation of position data at 60hz (~16ms) intervals.  When I try to use pandas 0.14 interpolation over the dataframe, it tells me I only have NaNs in my data set (not true).  When I try to run it over individual series pulled from the dataframe, it returns the same series without the NaNs filled in.  I've tried setting the indices to integers, using different methods, fiddling with the axis and limit parameters of the interpolation function - no dice.  What am I doing wrong?

```
df.head(5) : 
         x        y        ms
0  20.5815  14.1821  333.3333
1      NaN      NaN       350
2  20.6112  14.2013  366.6667
3      NaN      NaN  383.3333
4  20.5349  14.2232       400


df = df.set_index(df.ms) # set indices to milliseconds
```

When I try running

```
df.interpolate(method='values')
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-462-cb0f1f01eb84> in <module>()
     12 
     13 
---> 14 df.interpolate(method='values')
     15 
     16 

/Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in interpolate(self, method, axis, limit, inplace, downcast, **kwargs)
   2511 
   2512         if self._data.get_dtype_counts().get('object') == len(self.T):
-> 2513             raise TypeError("Cannot interpolate with all NaNs.")
   2514 
   2515         # create/use the index

TypeError: Cannot interpolate with all NaNs.
```

I've also tried running over individual series, which only return what I put in:

```
temp = df.x
temp.interpolate(method='values')

333.333333    20.5815
350.000000        NaN
366.666667    20.6112
383.333333        NaN
400.000000    20.5349 Name: x, dtype: object
```

**EDIT :**

Props to Jeff for inspiring the solution.

Adding:

```
df[['x','y','ms']] = df[['x','y','ms']].astype(float)
```

before

```
df.interpolate(method='values')
```

interpolation did the trick.

Comment: can u show df.info(); u prob have object dtypes

Comment: df0.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Float64Index: 100 entries, 0.0 to 1650.0
Data columns (total 3 columns):
x     46 non-null object
y     46 non-null object
ms    100 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)

Comment: they are object dtypes - should they be converted to something?

Comment: ``object`` dtypes are not good. only string-like should be ``object`` dtype. how did you generate/read these?

Comment: they were just fed in with vanilla pd.csv_read.  Only things I did was drop an extra header row with `df = df[1:].reset_index(drop=True)` and
 rename the columns with `df.rename(columns={'X center':'x', 'Y center': 'y'},inplace=True)`.  Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: extra header was prob a string row, use skip_rows (iirc is the option name), then won'tess with the type inferenece

Answer (score 2):

Based on your edit with props to Jeff for inspiring the solution.

Adding:

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

before

```
df.interpolate(method='values')
```

interpolation did the trick for me as well. Unless you're sub-selecting a column set, you don't need to specify the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to to reproduce the error (see below for a copy/paste-able example), can you make sure the the data you show is actually representative of your data?

```
In [137]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [138]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""         x        y        ms
     ...: 0  20.5815  14.1821  333.3333
     ...: 1      NaN      NaN       350
     ...: 2  20.6112  14.2013  366.6667
     ...: 3      NaN      NaN  383.3333
     ...: 4  20.5349  14.2232       400"""), delim_whitespace=True)

In [140]: df = df.set_index(df.ms)

In [142]: df.interpolate(method='values')
Out[142]: 
                 x         y        ms
ms                                    
333.3333  20.58150  14.18210  333.3333
350.0000  20.59635  14.19170  350.0000
366.6667  20.61120  14.20130  366.6667
383.3333  20.57305  14.21225  383.3333
400.0000  20.53490  14.22320  400.0000
```

Comment: I ran yours and it reproduced as well.  I also did the following to add the NaN rows: `df = df.reindex(pd.Series(arange(0,hz2ms(60)*100,hz2ms(60))))`, where hz2ms is a helper function that returns 1000/hz